# Pandas DataFrame aggregated column with names of other columns as value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I'm trying to create a new column in my `DataFrame` that is a list of aggregated column names.  Here's a sample `DataFrame`:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
               'B':[4,5,6],
               'C':[7,8,9],
               'D':[1,3,5],
               'E':[5,3,6],
               'F':[7,4,3]})
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3
```

I'd like to create a new column containing a list of column names where a certain condition is met.  Say that I'm interested in columns where value > 3 -- I would want an output that looks like this:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   A  B  C  D  E  F  Flag
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  ['B', 'C', 'E', 'F']
1  2  5  8  3  3  4  ['B', 'C', 'F']
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Currently, I'm using `apply`:

```
df['Flag'] = df.apply(lambda row: [list(df)[i] for i, j in enumerate(row) if j > 3], axis = 1)
```

This gets the job done, but feels clunky and I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`df.dot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) here:

```
df['Flag']=(df>3).dot(df.columns).apply(list)
print(df)
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F          Flag
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  [B, C, E, F]
1  2  5  8  3  3  4     [B, C, F]
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  [B, C, D, E]
```

Comment: `df.dot()` is definitely the most effective.  Wasn't thinking about matrix multiplication here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I still like for loop here

```
df['Flag']=[df.columns[x].tolist() for x in df.gt(3).values]
df
Out[968]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F          Flag
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  [B, C, E, F]
1  2  5  8  3  3  4     [B, C, F]
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  [B, C, D, E]
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a dataframe of `booleans` by checking which values are above a certain threshold with [`DataFrame.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html), and take the [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product with the column names. Finally use `apply(list)` to obtain lists from the resulting strings:

```
df['Flag'] = df.gt(3).dot(df.columns).apply(list)

   A  B  C  D  E  F          Flag
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  [B, C, E, F]
1  2  5  8  3  3  4     [B, C, F]
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  [B, C, D, E]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
df['Flag'] = df.T.apply(lambda x: list(x[x>3].index))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: *adding timing for all solutions of this question*

I prefer a solution without `apply`

```
df['Flag'] = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index', value_name='val', var_name='col').query('val > 3').groupby('index')['col'].agg(list)
```

Or

```
df['Flag'] = df.stack().rename('val').reset_index(level=1).query('val > 3').groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(list)

Out[2576]:
   A  B  C  D  E  F          Flag
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  [B, C, E, F]
1  2  5  8  3  3  4     [B, C, F]
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  [B, C, D, E]
```

---

Test data:

```
a = [
    [1,  4,  7,  1,  5,  7],
    [2,  5,  8,  3,  3,  4],
    [3,  6,  9,  5,  6,  3],
    ] * 10000

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = list('ABCDEF'))
```

Timing with `%timeit`:

```
In [79]: %timeit (df>3).dot(df.columns).apply(list)
40.8 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [80]: %timeit [df.columns[x].tolist() for x in df.gt(3).values]
1.23 s ± 10.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [81]: %timeit df.gt(3).dot(df.columns).apply(list)
37.6 ms ± 644 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [82]: %timeit df.T.apply(lambda x: list(x[x>3].index))
16.4 s ± 99.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [83]: %timeit df.stack().rename('val').reset_index(level=1).query('val > 3')
    ...: .groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(list)
4.05 s ± 15.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [84]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[np.argwhere(x>3).ravel()].values
    ...: , 1)
c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:56: Future
Warning: Series.nonzero() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Use Series.to_numpy().nonzero() instead
  return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
12 s ± 45.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Fastest are solution using `.dot`

Comment: The timing is very useful!  I was actually about to do this myself, as my dataset is 2mm+ rows so I was looking for the quickest option.  `apply` was moving very slow

Answer (score 0):

Using [numpy.argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) and `ravel()`:

```
   df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[np.argwhere(x>3).ravel()].values, 1)
```

Comment: Your answer could use a brief explanation so that others may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

we can use `@` also

```
df['Flag'] = ((df >3) @ df.columns).map(list)
```